# Reading a file line-by-line in bash

Tags: linux, bash

Trying to read a file line by line, but its not working, tried many different ways including below:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo 'line1
line2
line3
line4
;;' > list.txt

IFS=$'\n'

for line in "$(cat list.txt)"
do
   echo "line=$line"
   echo "----"
done
```

When I run:

```
$ ./test.sh
line=line1
line2
line3
line4
;;
----
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you have used quotes around command substitution, `$()`, the shell is not performing word splitting on newline (`IFS=$'\n'`) (and pathname expansion), hence the whole content of the file will be taken as a single string (the first `line` has it), instead of newline separated ones to iterate over.

You need to remove the quotes:

```
for line in $(cat list.txt)
```

[Although it is not recommended to iterate over lines of a file using `for`-`cat` combo](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), use [`while`-`read`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) instead:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do ...;  done <list.txt
```